# \usepackage[slantedGreek]{newtxmath}: \mathsf{\upOmega} won't render

Tags: greek, capitalization, sans-serif, newtxmath, newtx

Feeding

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\(\mathsf{\upOmega}\)
\end{document}
```

to any of `[ps|pdf|lua|xe]latex` results in a dot

[image: dot]

Is it a bug or a feature? (This question is rhetorical, so, choose the answer you like.)

When compiling with `pdflatex`, we would like to have `newtx` fonts (for UTF8 compilers: Times-like fonts) in general, italics serif Latin math and italics serif Greek math by default. Still, from time to time we'd like to typeset some upright sans-serif Greek math letter (in my case, the upright sans-serif Greek capital Omega). Of course, you could `tikz` the symbol, but then it wouldn't show up in the text layer of the PDF generated.  The package `upgreek` would do the job but increase the vertical spacing a little. So: what's the best possible way to typeset upright sans serif Greek capital Omega without drawing it and without loading (all of) `upgreek` in the above setting? It is really about that Omega; I don't need other Greek symbols.

Recently, @egreg [suggested](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483720) adding `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}` to solve the problem. This solution changes the output, though slightly. The minimal example is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek]{newtxmath}%%% In particular, loads the upright versions of greek as \upalpha, \upbeta, ...
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n} % newtxmath has T1, should be OT1 instead to be able to display \mathsf{\upOmega}.
\newcommand{\shortDefiningEquals}{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\begin{document}
\(\shortDefiningEquals\)\\

\(\shortDefiningEquals\)

\strut\\
\begin{itemize}
\item \strut\\\\$\shortDefiningEquals$
\end{itemize}
\strut\\\\$\mathsf{dp}^1$
\end{document}
```

The existence of the differences can be proven running `pdflatex` on the version with the suggested line, then on the version without the suggested line, and then comparing the two by the tool diffpdf:

[image: differences]

A better understanding of how small the differences may be can be obtained by running `latex`+`dvips` on the two versions (with/without the line) and comparing the resulting postscript files with  `diff -a -C 5 version1.ps version2.ps | tail -24`:

```
*** 2221,2231 ****
   end
  %%EndSetup
  %%Page: 1 1
  TeXDict begin 1 0 bop 639 489 a Fh(def)652 538 y Fe(=)639
  788 y Fh(def)652 837 y Fe(=)652 1352 y Fd(\210)722 1602
! y Fh(def)735 1650 y Fe(=)515 2165 y Fc(dp)598 2133 y
  Fb(1)1926 5255 y Fa(1)p eop end
  %%Trailer

  userdict /end-hook known{end-hook}if
  %%EOF
--- 2221,2231 ----
   end
  %%EndSetup
  %%Page: 1 1
  TeXDict begin 1 0 bop 639 489 a Fh(def)652 538 y Fe(=)639
  788 y Fh(def)652 837 y Fe(=)652 1352 y Fd(\210)722 1602
! y Fh(def)735 1650 y Fe(=)515 2165 y Fc(dp)598 2134 y
  Fb(1)1926 5255 y Fa(1)p eop end
  %%Trailer

  userdict /end-hook known{end-hook}if
  %%EOF
```

I'm unsure whether other, bigger differences may emerge.

Comment: The tiny difference can be reproduced with just `$\mathsf{dp}^1$`. Such a difference doesn't seem so big to be worrying.

Comment: Yes. Just that.

Comment: I guess it's just the exponent. I don't know the precise reason: it doesn't happen with `\mathsf{p}^1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newtxmath` chooses for `\mathsf` a T1-encoded font, which has the dot accent at the position where OT1-encoded fonts have an Omega. Fix it.

This is independent on the option `slantedGreek`, as far as I can see.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek]{newtxmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n} % newtxmath has T1

\begin{document}
X\(\mathsf{\upOmega}\)X
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user49915 `\mathsf`, as defined by `newtxmath`, uses `T1/qhv/m/n`, I just change T1 to OT1. The shape of Latin letters should be exactly the same, as both are virtual fonts taking the Latin letters from the same source.

Comment: @user49915 I don't have `diffpdf`, but [`diff-pdf`](https://vslavik.github.io/diff-pdf/) finds no difference when the single formula `$\stackrel{\text{def}}{\Leftrightarrow}\sum$` is in the document.

Comment: @user49915 Of course that's possible. A better idea, in my opinion, would be to investigate on why you get differences: can you please show a minimal example that produces differences when `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}` is enabled?

Comment: I want to use this but when I do the sans font only works with capital Greek letters. What should be included to work with lower case Greek?

Comment: @JPeterson Not with this strategy, I'm afraid.